# jquery mobile button doesn't come up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.2, and whenever I press the button, the button shows the style of being pressed, but then it never come back up again.

HTML:

```
<form id="login_form">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-role="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function()
{
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    var options = {
        url:API_SERVER_URL+"/login",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data.success)
            {

                $.mobile.changePage('success.html', {transition: "slide"});
            }else
            {
                alert("failed:("); 
            }
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('cannot connect');
        }
    };
    options = $.extend(DEFAULT_AJAX_OPTIONS, options);
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

[image: How it looks after being pressed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ui-btn-active` when form is submitted.

```
$("#login_form").on("submit", function () {
  $("[type=submit]").closest('div').removeClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RRpG2/)**

Comment: I thought this behavior would be automatic. Or is it because it's a submit event?

Comment: @JonathanChow submit buttons dont work the same way as anchor buttons, what's why you need to remove classes manually. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G3DbA/